# Basic Javascript programming

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS programming and I'm wondering what's wrong with the code below?

I simply cannot get it to display anything?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Creating and using an object method.</p>
<p>An object method is a function definition, stored as a property value.</p>
<p><a href="#" onClick="typemodelcolour();">Click here</a></p>
<script>
var car = {
    type: "BMW",
    model: "350",
    colour: "Grey",
    typemodelcolour: function() {
        alert("Your car is a " + this.colour + " " + this.type + " " + this.model)
    };
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure it's something pretty basic knowing me :)

Comment: Use your developer console. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Answer (score 2):

You create an `Object` `car` (or sometimes called a hash) that has the property `typemodelcolour` of type `Function`.

Now that you defined the function, you need to call it:

```
car.typemodelcolour();
```

And please use something like a camel case notation to make your code readable: `car.typeModelColour` instead of `car.typemodelcolour`.

Comment: There is also a syntax error, Using `;` after defining a method.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking your method incorrectly. Because you've declared the method as an object within the `car` object, you must access it as a property of that `car` object:

```
onclick="typemodelcolour()"
```

should, in fact, be:

```
onclick="car.typemodelcolour()"
```

---

As other answerers point out, another place where you went wrong was including the superfluous semicolon in your method's definition. You have:

```
function(){alert("Your car is a " + this.colour + " " + this.type + " " + this.model)};
```

Expanded out, this looks a bit like this:

```
function() {
    alert("Your car is a " + this.colour + " " + this.type + " " + this.model)
};
```

It doesn't make any sense in Javascript to terminate a bracketed statement with a semicolon, therefore it's unneccessary:

```
function(){alert("Your car is a " + this.colour + " " + this.type + " " + this.model)}
```

Answer (score 0):

*In javascript object their should no semi-colon.*

```
var car = {
    type  : "BMW",
    model : "350",
    colour: "Grey",
    typemodelcolour: function(){alert("Your car is a " + this.colour + " " + 
this.type + " " + this.model)} //<== Remove the Semi colon
};
```

and also it should be:

```
onclick="car.typemodelcolour()"
```

when you call it

Answer (score 0):

```js
function typemodelcolour(){
    var type="BMW";
    var model= "350";
    var colour="Grey";    
        alert("Your car is a " + type+ " " +model + " " + colour)    
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Creating and using an object method.</p>
<p>An object method is a function definition, stored as a property value.</p>
<p><a href="#" onClick="typemodelcolour();">Click here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```